# Extract text from string using a wildca

Tags: excel, excel-formula

5532/367/3400/421.0

lets say for example that was the string in the cell in excel.
and all i wanted to extract was the 3400. how would i Use mid or right function to achieve this. I tried using a wildcard character but it kept giving an error.

`=MID(u4,FIND("*/*/";u4);4)`

that was what i was trying but it errors out.

All of the numbers can be anywhere from 3 to 5 characters long so i cant anticipate the exact length of original string.

Im sure its a simple solution but I'm drawing a blank here.

Comment: Are you trying to extract everything between the 2nd and 3rd forward slash?

Comment: That's correct, the format will always be the same. Just the number length changes